# Why does exponential notation with decimal values fail?

Tags: python, floating-point, ieee-754, exponent

Conventionally `1e3` means `10**3`.

```
>>> 1e3
1000.0
>>> 10**3
1000
```

Similar case is `exp(3)` compared to `e**3`.

```
>>> exp(3)
20.085536923187668
>>> e**3
20.085536923187664
```

However now notice if the exponent is a `float` value:

```
>>> exp(3.1)
22.197951281441636
>>> e**3.1
22.197951281441632
```

which is fine. Now for the first example:

```
>>> 1e3.1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    1e3.1
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> 10**3.1
1258.9254117941675
```

which shows `Python` does not like `1e3.1`, `Fortran` too.
Regardless it could be a standard (!) why it is like that?

Comment: why does visual basic use `'` as the comment char, which in any other non-insane language is used for strings? it's how the language designers wanted it. if you want to rant, rant at them.

Comment: @MarcB Think always positive, then you will notice the point behind the question. Your example `'` is not relevant!

Comment: I, for one, do not see why I am not allowed to write `2(1.5)3` for `218`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The notation with the `e` is a numeric literal, part of the lexical syntax of many programming languages, based on standard form/scientific notation.

The purpose of this notation is to allow you to specify very large/small numbers by shifting the point position. It's not intended to allow you to encode multiplication by some arbitrary power of 10 into numeric literals. Therefore, that point and the following digits aren't even recognised as part of the numeric literal token.

If you want arbitrary powers, as you've found, there are math functions and operators that do the job. Unlike a numeric literal, you even get to determine the parameter values at run-time.

Answer (score 5):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal-objects):

```
sign           ::=  '+' | '-'
digit          ::=  '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9'
indicator      ::=  'e' | 'E'
digits         ::=  digit [digit]...
decimal-part   ::=  digits '.' [digits] | ['.'] digits
exponent-part  ::=  indicator [sign] digits            #no dots allowed here
```

Comment: Nice + upvote. BTW it is the same in `Fortran`. Would be better if you could try explain `why`.

Comment: @Developer programming languages try to stick to the [IEEE floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) standard, which says that the exponent part must be  an integer.

Comment: Thanks for the point and link, Ashwini.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be conflating syntax for literals with operators.  While you can claim that 1e3.1 follows your "convention" it should be quite clear that 1e3.1 is not a valid literal expression to the Python interpeter.  The language has a defined standard grammar, and that grammer doesn't support floating point literal expressions as "exponents" for its numeric literals.

The "e" in a Python numeric literal is not an operator (any more than the decimal point would be).  So your expectation that Python's literal syntax should support some "convention" ... based on some pattern you've divined ... is not particularly reasonable.

Comment: Thanks + one upvote. Apparently it is just an agreement done already, otherwise, it would not be that difficult recognising `1e3.1` as a number by compiler. BTW it is the same in `Fortran`.

Comment: Our answers passed in the 'net.  I saw yours come in after mine was posted even though it appeared above mine.